# get all matching non null elements if all the conditions are given in predicate

Tags: java, java-8, predicate

How to get all elements with id = 2?

The below code is giving only the last one i.e. `channelMetadataDetail3`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class APICheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<ChannelMetadataDetails> channelMetadataDetails = 
        new ArrayList<ChannelMetadataDetails>();
        ChannelMetadataDetails channelMetadataDetail1 = 
        new ChannelMetadataDetails();
        channelMetadataDetail1.setId("2");
        channelMetadataDetail1.setUnitOfMeasureId("3");

        ChannelMetadataDetails channelMetadataDetail2 = 
        new ChannelMetadataDetails();
        channelMetadataDetail2.setId("2");
        channelMetadataDetail2.setUnitOfMeasureId("3");
        channelMetadataDetail2.setMeasureTypeId("5");

        ChannelMetadataDetails channelMetadataDetail3 = 
        new ChannelMetadataDetails();
        channelMetadataDetail3.setId("2");

        channelMetadataDetails.add(channelMetadataDetail1);
        channelMetadataDetails.add(channelMetadataDetail2);
        channelMetadataDetails.add(channelMetadataDetail3);

        channelMetadataDetails =channelMetadataDetails.
        stream().filter(cm -> cm.getId().equals("2")).
        filter(cm -> cm.getUnitOfMeasureId().equals(null)).
        filter(cm -> cm.getMeasureTypeId().equals(null)).
        collect(Collectors.toList());

    }   

}
```

*NOTE:*- If `cm.getUnitOfMeasureId()` is null then I will get `NullPointerException`

**UPDATE:**

In short, I only want those objects whose elements are non-null.

For example using for loop:

```
for (ChannelMetadataDetails cmEach : channelMetadataDetails) {
            if(cmEach.getId() != null && cmEach.getUnitOfMeasureId() == null && cmEach.getMeasureTypeId() == null) {
                channelMetadataDetails.stream().filter(cm -> cm.getId().equals("2")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            } else if(cmEach.getId() == null && cmEach.getUnitOfMeasureId() != null && cmEach.getMeasureTypeId() == null) {
                channelMetadataDetails.stream().filter(cm -> cm.getUnitOfMeasureId().equals("4")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            } else if(cmEach.getId() == null && cmEach.getUnitOfMeasureId() == null && cmEach.getMeasureTypeId() != null) {
                channelMetadataDetails.stream().filter(cm -> cm.getMeasureTypeId().equals("5")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            } else if(cmEach.getId() != null && cmEach.getUnitOfMeasureId() != null && cmEach.getMeasureTypeId() == null) {
                channelMetadataDetails.stream().filter(cm -> cm.getId().equals("2") && cm.getUnitOfMeasureId().equals("4")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            } else if(cmEach.getId() != null && cmEach.getUnitOfMeasureId() == null && cmEach.getMeasureTypeId() != null) {
                channelMetadataDetails.stream().filter(cm -> cm.getId().equals("2") && cm.getMeasureTypeId().equals("5")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            } else if(cmEach.getId() != null && cmEach.getUnitOfMeasureId() != null && cmEach.getMeasureTypeId() != null) {
                channelMetadataDetails.stream().filter(cm -> cm.getId().equals("2") && cm.getUnitOfMeasureId().equals("4") && cm.getMeasureTypeId().equals("5")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
        }
```

Comment: `cm.getId() == "2"` - use equals

Comment: @Eran- I agree but this will give `NullPointerException` if the `getId()` is null or if the `getUnitOfMeasureId()` is null or if the `getMeasureTypeId()` is null.

Comment: @Eran - Please reopen as I have edited the question.

Comment: When `getId()` can return null you need a null-check. `cm.getId() != null && cm.getId().equals("2")`. Also `cm.getUnitOfMeasureId().equals(null)` would throw a NullPointerException or return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you only get the last element is that your second and third filters require that `cm.getUnitOfMeasureId()` and `cm.getMeasureTypeId()` are null. That's only true for the last element. If you only want to filter by `getId()`, remove the other filters:

```
channelMetadataDetails =
    channelMetadataDetails.stream()
                          .filter(cm -> cm.getId() != null && cm.getId().equals("2"))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT:

Based on your edit, you want at least one of the 3 properties to have a value, and you want to check all the not-null values:

```
channelMetadataDetails =
    channelMetadataDetails.stream()
                          .filter(cm -> cm.getId() != null || cm.getUnitOfMeasureId() != null || cm.getMeasureTypeId() != null)
                          .filter(cm -> cm.getId() == null || cm.getId().equals("2"))
                          .filter(cm -> cm.getUnitOfMeasureId() == null || cm.getUnitOfMeasureId().equals("4"))
                          .filter(cm -> cm.getMeasureTypeId() == null || cm.cm.getMeasureTypeId().equals("5"))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I want to filter by `getId()`, `getUnitOfMeasureId()` and `getMeasureTypeId()`. But these three are coming dynamic. So which one will be null that I don't know in advance. One way is to use multiple if-else conditions to check what is null and what's not and then use filters. But that's odd. Isn't there any method in Predicates that do this for me?

Comment: @MyGod if you clarify what the exact filtering logic should be, I might be able to answer that. In the question you only asked for filtering by one field - `How to get all elements with id = 2`.

Comment: See my update in above question. I only want those objects whose elements are non-null. So I don't want `3^3 = 9` if-else conditions to check what's null and what's not null.

Comment: So if I change `channelMetadataDetail1.setId("2")` to `channelMetadataDetail1.setId("8")` then it should not give this object. But as per your edit code, it is giving `channelMetadataDetail1` whose id is even 8. I only want the non-null matching ones.

Comment: @MyGod given the `.filter(cm -> cm.getId() == null || cm.getId().equals("2"))` filter, there's no way it will pass if `cm.getID().equals("8")`

Comment: It is passing and here is the output: `[unitOfMeasureId: 3, measureTypeId: null, id: 8]`, `[unitOfMeasureId: 3, measureTypeId: 5, id: 2]`, `[unitOfMeasureId: null, measureTypeId: null, id: 2]`

Comment: So it is giving all the objects regardless of what matches and what not matches..just that what not matches is coming as `null` in the list.

Comment: @MyGod Perhaps you are not running the same code as in my answer, or perhaps there is some issue elsewhere (such as in your `ChannelMetadataDetails` class).

Comment: There was a issue in my class. I had overridden the toString method in that class `@Override
 public String toString() {
  return "unitOfMeasureId: "+unitOfMeasureId+ ", measureTypeId: "+measureTypeId+ ", id: "+id;
 }`

Comment: And was doing `System.out.println("channelMetadataDetails: "+channelMetadataDetails.toString());`

Comment: @MyGod Maybe it would be a good idea to move all the filtering logic to a method that returns `boolean` in the `ChannelMetadataDetails` class. This way, you would only need to do one `filter` operation in the stream.